# Likelihood of a random vector with each component following a different distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, likelihood

How do you write down the likelihood for random vectors when each component follows a different distribution with a dependence structure?

For example, Suppose there are n-random vectors, mutually independent, $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ with 3 components of each vector, i.e. $X_i=[X_{i,1},X_{i,2},X_{i,3}],i=1,\ldots,n$. Suppose $X_{i,1:2}\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $X_{i,3}\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. Also $\text{Cov}(X_{i,1},X_{i,3})=a_1$ and $\text{Cov}(X_{i,2},X_{i,3})=a_2$. Then what is the likelihood of this model?

Comment: Are X_{i,1} and X_{i,2} independent? Are X_{i} independent for all *i*? By the likelihood, do you mean the probability density for this three-variate pdf?

Comment: @Alex X_{i,1} and X_{i,2} need not be independent, $\Sigma$ could have non-zero off-diagonal elements. $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are mutually independent. Yes, I am looking for the three-variate pdf.

Comment: You cannot derive joint distribution simply by knowing marginal distributions.

Comment: @StubbornAtom There is also information about the covariance between each component. What is the sufficient amount of information needed to obtain the joint distribution?

Comment: Reading up on *copulas* might give you a place to start.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you!